# AS3- Video does not play in loaded SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, flv

I have multiple SWF and FLA files. The first swf file contains a video and it basically plays but when i loaded *another* SWF that is basically a continuation of the first (that also contains a video) it doesn't play.

This is how i redirected to the other swf file.

```
button_oldman.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_13);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_13(event:MouseEvent):void
{
removeChildren();
myLoader.load(url);                           // load the SWF file
addChild(myLoader); 
}
```

I don't know why the video doesn't play when it is loaded from another file. It does play when i test it by itself (not testing from the other swf) . How do i fix this?

Comment: Insufficient given info. Is video embedded or external? Does the loading itself work correctly or not (you provided only part of the code so there's no telling)?

Comment: it is not embedded I just call it. the loading itself does work its just that when i load the swf via the other swf the video inside it doesnt play anymore.

Comment: You cannot *call a video*. You can either embed it or load an external file via NetConnection -> NetStream -> Video (or use FLVPlayback component which is basically the latter).

Comment: I used the FLVPlayback but it wont play it just shows the video skin

Comment: i fixed this already thanks for your help